# HTML5/CSS3 - Problems with margin-left

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm with a problem here and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I would like to understand why can't I apply "margin-left" on "Bruna Diniz" post, in the section I applied a class called "post__box" which has a "margin-left: 20px" attrib, I tried to override it with a "margin-left: 40px" class but it just don't work, if I apply this class in a div wrapping all it's child elements it don't work the same way, I mean, I wanna move the entire section to the left and not affect/reduce it's inner child elements size, you know?

Thanks for all the patience since now <3 -- and the comment/warning below, sorry about that (:

the images of what's happening:

[image: Bruna Diniz (and other posts) margin issue]

and finally my HTML5 (important parts !!!!) code:

```
    <!-- bruna diniz  -->
    <section class="posts__box posts__box--left -margin-left-40px">

      <div class="-margin-top-47px">

        <div class="box--text -font-left">
          <a class="--hover" href="revista\artistas\bruna-diniz.html">
            <p class="-font-black -font-source -font--text-big">corpo estrangeiro sem imagem<br>
             um espelho vazio que não sou capaz de ver e já não sei se um dia verei<br>
             se quer serei capaz de pintar algum rosto que imagino ser o meu<br>
             qualquer imagem que nos dissesse sobre aquele fio de navalha<br>
             pelo qual percorri e ainda percorrerei<br>
             imagine só o que serão nossos filhos<br>
             nossas filhas<br>
             que ainda não são frutos<br>
             e se forem algum, de quais flores irão nascer? (...)</p>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="box--author box--btn box--btn--black">
          <a class="--hover" href="revista\artistas\bruna-diniz.html">
            <h4 class="box--author--text author--white -font--small --hover--dimgray">Bruna Diniz</h4>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="box--continue box--btn box--btn--red">
          <a class="--hover" href="revista\artistas\bruna-diniz.html">
            <h5 class="box--continue--text continue--white -font--tiny --hover--dimgray">CONTINUAR A LEITURA</h5>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </section>
```

MY CSS3 code:

```
/* BLOCKS */

/* posts */

.box--btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px dimgray;
}

.posts__box {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}

.box--title {
  text-align: center;
}

.box--img {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px Dimgray;
}

.box--text {
  padding: 5px;
}

.box--author {
  float: right;
  width: 46%;
  height: 50px;
}

.box--author--text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.box--continue {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  height: 50px;
}

.box--continue--text {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.posts__btns {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}


/* MODIFIERS */

.revista__posts--height {
  height: 3000px;
}


/* posts */

.title--red {
  color: rgba(233, 26, 26, 1);
}

.title--size-small {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px black;
}

.title--size-large {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px black;
}

.box--btn--red {
  background: rgba(233, 26, 26, 1);
}

.continue--white {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px black;
}

.box--btn--black {
  background: #212121;
}

.author--white {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.posts__box--left {
  float: left;
}

.posts__box--right {
  float: right;
}

.posts__box--margin--fix--left {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.posts__box--margin--fix--top {
  margin-top: 34px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.posts__btns--left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.posts__btns--right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* revista */

.revista__container--height {
  height: 4800px;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the Minimal part of giving the required example: [mcve] Nobody's going to wade through all that. Your question is also far too broad. Limit yourself to one problem at a time. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry about that, I will edit my post (:

Answer (score 1):

You have this class "**-margin-left-40px**" in your section but you haven't defined css for this class. Define it and I think it will work.

```
 -margin-left-40px {
     margin-left:40px !important;
  }
```

Comment: I defined, just didn't post this global clumpsy margin classes (yes, is more than one) to don't polute too much the post at all. Forgot to mention it, sorry. But yes, just reinforcing "-margin-left-40px" is a "margin-left: 40px" global class (used only in this "post__box").

Comment: but cool tip! "!important" really override previous attribs and made it work! thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

You haven't definied css for this class '-margin-left-40px'. Please add a following code in a css and i hope it will help you

```
 .-margin-left-40px {
     margin-left:40px;
  }
```

If its not overriding the css then you can use !important like in a below code:

```
.-margin-left-40px {
    margin-left:40px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first add **-margin-left-40px** in your CSS, that might still not work as your making the third boxe float right and you're using this for every boxes.

```
.posts__box {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

I will suggest you give the right floating box is margin like this

```
.posts__box__right {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 30%;
 }
```

then apply the **"-margin-left-40px"** to **bruna diniz** as you did.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll apply it later <3